# Как в списке сослаться на предыдущий элемент в Python

Tags: python

Нужно, чтобы программа складывала значения предыдущего и следующего  значений числа в списке.
Например, дан рад чисел: 1 5 8 2
Для элемента [1] (5) ответом будет 9 - складываем 1 и 8
PS. С крайними элементами проблем нет: "Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними, одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце этого списка"

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то задача решается следующим образом:

```
a=[1,4,5,8,22,34]

for elem in range(len(a)):
    print(a[elem-1]+a[(elem+1)%len(a)])
```

Результат:

```
38
6
12
27
42
23
```

Answer (score 1):

Python стимулирует использовать не индексный, а декларативный способ манипуляции со списками. В данном случае, он не так красив чем обычно.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

arr = [1, 5, 8, 2]

for a, b in zip(arr, islice(cycle(arr), 2, None)):
    print(f'{a} + {b} = {a+b}')
```

> 1 + 8 = 9
>   5 + 2 = 7
>   8 + 1 = 9
>   2 + 5 = 7

Если же нужно знать элемент для которого ищутся соседи, то можно так:

```
arr = [1, 5, 8, 2]
length = len(arr)
arr3 = arr * 3

for n, a, b in zip(arr, arr3[length-1:], arr3[length+1:]):
    print(f'{n}: {a} + {b} = {a+b}')
```

> 1: 2 + 5 = 7
>   5: 1 + 8 = 9
>   8: 5 + 2 = 7
>   2: 8 + 1 = 9